# How to get WPF gridview row values programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview

We have lots of `ListViews` with a `GridView` view that are bound to a `ViewModelCollection<T>`. Now I need to get the *displayed values* (as string) from the `GridView`. It seems that I cannot access the rows from `GridView` class.

I don't know what type the `GridView` is showing, so I cannot use `ListView.ItemCollection` either. Also I don't know the name of the `GridView` because the code isn't in the code behind (trying to follow MVVM pattern). I just need the values that are being displayed, so that I can export them to Excel sheet (the column order is also important).

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the ViewModelCollection to get the data.  If you lose formatting, just apply same formatting rules on the fields.  Better, I would expose string properties in the ViewModelCollection with respective formatting, and bind the grid view to them.

Comment: Yes but what about the column ordering? And the fact that GridView doesn't necessarily show all properties from the ViewModel?

Comment: Then get the CollectionView for the grid, and access data from there.  See this for more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx, and then this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

By using the DataRowView you can get the each and every cell value.

```
DataRowView row = (DataRowView)grid_view.SelectedItems[0];
cmbx_name.Text = row.Row.ItemArray[0].ToString();
lbl_date.Text = row.Row.ItemArray[1].ToString();
txt_location.Text = row.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();
txt_vehicleno.Text = row.Row.ItemArray[5].ToString();
cmbx_source.Text = row.Row.ItemArray[6].ToString();
orderid = row.Row.ItemArray[7].ToString();
custid = row.Row.ItemArray[8].ToString();
```